# Typescript Deployment issues (no issues local deployment)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, node-modules, aws-amplify

I am working on a typescript website that is hosted on AWS amplify through a Github repo and I have been having intermittent issues deploying the site. Normally, the site builds properly and without major issues/impediments, but occasionally, the site will fail on the frontend portion of the build.

The primary error that it gives is:

```
2021-09-24T02:11:16.620Z [WARNING]: There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
                                    It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.
                                    The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:
                                    "babel-loader": "8.1.0"
Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
                                    However, a different version of babel-loader was detected higher up in the tree:
                                    /codebuild/output/--/--/--/node_modules/babel-loader (version: 8.2.2)
                                    Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.
```

It goes on to detail some steps to take in order to remedy the issue, which I have tried unsuccessfully a number of times (delete locks, node module folder, remove babel-loader from package.json) I also tried adding SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to a .env file. Doing this resolved *that* error, but brought up another error as detailed here:

```
2021-09-24T02:07:11.394Z [INFO]: ./node_modules/@usedapp/core/node_modules/ethers/lib.esm/utils.js 30:0-32:73
                                 Attempted import error: 'TransactionTypes' is not exported from '@ethersproject/transactions'.
```

Again, the compilation works on my personal machine, and only presents (intermittent) issues upon attempting to build the same Github repo on Amazon Amplify

Please let me know if you have any thoughts or suggestions!

-Snips

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the lib you are using didn't export something you need, if you control the lib you should export it.
Make sure you set `"isolatedModules": true` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Hi Nathaniel, thanks for the response. The library I am using is imported, and the build that broke did not have any difference with regard to usage of that particular library at all. Also, "isolatedModules" in tsconfig.json is indeed set to true